# How do I access a variable in the viewcontroller from within a custom view?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a viewcontroller with a variable called conversationID.  In this viewcontroller I have a custom view with it's own class.  How can I access the userID variable from within the custom view class?

Comment: you need to create shared instance for custom view and pass it when you create object of your custom view

Comment: @MikeAlter you should never create a shared instance for views.

Comment: Why do you need to access `userID` from the view? Are you trying to present it there?

Comment: Because I run a function in the view class to the firebasedata class to put x/y points into the database.  It's a drawing app.  So I need to get them to either the view class or the firebasedata class, so I can put the user's drawings under his own ID in firebase.

Comment: you know, I think i have a sharedinstance for the firebase class, maybe I could just bypass the custom view and just send it there.  I was going to just pass it thru a function to get it there anyway.

Comment: @AndreyGordeev can you please explain why we should never create shared instance of view , is it create problem ?

Comment: @MikeAlter views are not supposed to be singletons, as a view controller already holds a reference to a view. Besides, what if the user close the view controller and opens it again? The view controller must instantiate a new instance of view, while the singleton will preserve the old state of the view.

Comment: @AndreyGordeev thnx for reply , now i have clear my doubt , what i did understand is that he has separate class of uiview (not added in storyboard) and need to pass user id when show that view

Comment: the view is in storyboard, but it's in each table cell.  So it's in a table cell prototype. 2 of them actually

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
1. Set your customViews customClass in storyBoard.
2. Make an outlet for custom View
3. Now you can access UserId using..
         YourViewController.custonView.userId

Comment: but the reference to the custom view is in a table cell class

Comment: I don't see how this would even work anyway.  This makes no sense

Comment: Custom class is for table cell or any view in table cell.